# Deduce the irreducible representations of $A_4$ from the fundamental representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Knowing that the irreducible representations of $A_4$ are three with dimension 1, and one with dim 3, deduce them from the fundamental representation of $A_4$.

**My attempt**

Since $A_4$ is generated by $(12)(34)$ and $(123)$, The fundamental representation in the basis $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is given by
$$D((12)(34))=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\\end{pmatrix}\qquad D(123)=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}$$

Now I don't know how to proceed... Is there a general approach for problems like this? Thanks in advance.

---

I know that in $S_3$ I can choose $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(|1\rangle+|2\rangle+|3\rangle$) as a invariant subspace, and two other orthonormal vectors, and if I do the change of basis the resulting matrices are in fact block-diagonal.

I think that in this case I have to do something similar.

Comment: From this representation you will only find as components the trivial representation (as the action is transitive) and the irreducible representation of degree $3$ (as the action is $2$-transitive). Since the exercise also asks for the other two representations of degree  $1$, the *fundamental* representation is possibly a reference to the (right) *regular* representation.

Comment: Do you know about tensor products of representations? A theorem of burnside shows they yield all from one faithful. (As constituents)

Comment: I've never heard about the Burnside's theorem

Comment: do you know how to complete the character table for $A_4$ using the information you have?  Characters are quite informative for 1 dimensional representations....